# Отобразить конкретные значения в pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вывести только конкретные значения при использовании функции `value_counts`?

Код:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=";", encoding="utf-8").fillna("Null")
df.head()
id = df["ID"].value_counts()
print(id)
```

исходный файл `CSV` имеет два столбца.

получаю:

| id | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 532 |
| 2 | 2355 |
| 3 | 1235 |
| 4 | 6631 |
| ... | ... |
| 100 | 569 |

Как отобразить только `id` которые необходимы, например, `20,30,40,50,60`

Столбец `id` имеет строковые значения, т.е. это не порядковый столбец.

Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант вроде должно и так сработать. Если такие значения есть в индексе после применения `value_counts`, т.е. они есть в `id` в исходном `df`:

```
vc = df["ID"].value_counts()
print(vc.loc[['20','30','40','50','60']])
```

Я заменил имя переменной/датафрейма с результатом применения `value_counts`, потому что `id` - это название встроенной функции языка питон, его лучше не использовать для своих переменных.

Comment: Спасибо за совет с переменными.

Попробовал Ваш вариант, вылетает много ошибок. В конце пишет:

`KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([20, 22, 79], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"`

Comment: Добавил кавычки в `print(vc.loc[["20","30","40","50","60"]])` - заработало. Спасибо, то что нужно.

Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой ответ, отмечу.

Comment: @AlexRebell Посмотите в свой вопрос, у вас в нём написано без кавычек: `20,30,40,50,60`, если у вас в столбце `id` это на самом деле строки, а не числа, тогда конечно нужны кавычки, но из вашего вопроса этого нигде не видно. Обозначьте этот факт как-то в вопросе, тогда поправлю. А сейчас будет несоответствие ответа вопросу, если я у себя исправлю.

Comment: Понял, указал, что в столбце `id` строковые значения.

Comment: Ок, поставил кавычки )

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать отфильтровать через `isin()`:

```
print(df[df['ID'].isin([20, 30, 40, 50, ])].value_counts())
```

Если нужно только посчитать повторение `ID`, то:

```
print(df[df['ID'].isin([20, 30, 40, 50, ])].value_counts('ID'))
```

Можно еще по этой выборке посчитать повторение `Count`:

```
print(df[df['ID'].isin([20, 30, 40, 50, ])].value_counts('Count'))
```

Comment: Попробовал Ваш вариант, в `Pycharm` выводит: `Series([], dtype: int64)`

Comment: добавил кавычки в условие: `isin(["20", "30", "40", "50"])]` - заработало, но данный пример не подсчитывает количество встречающихся значений в документе, а выводит всю строку. Тоже полезный пример. Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть. Мне лень было набивать текстовик. Я через цикл наполнил DataFrame. Выводится строка, а за ней третьей колонкой количество.

Comment: Хотя нет. У меня импорт csv происходит сразу с конвертацией значений и не требует кавычек. В моем случае суммирование производится, когда строка повторяется. У Вас в csv все в кавычках получается?

Comment: Нет, в `CSV` файле значения без кавычек.

Comment: Добавил вариант для подсчета только числа вхождений по `ID` в той форме, что у меня показана.

Comment: `print(df[df['ID'].isin(["20", "30", "40"])].value_counts('ID'))` - этот вариант подходит. спасибо.